# Weird error while linking: duplicate symbol _comparePutFoldersFirst

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker, clang

I'm having a weird behavior during linking in my project.

The problem is I have a library linked to my project, and I'm currently working on moving some generic classes from the proj to the library.

MyClass2 is basically the same as MyClass this means that there are some properties that have the same name oin both classes, but the name of the classes (and files) are different, so I don't know why the linking error is happening.

The exact error is the following:

```
duplicate symbol _comparePutFoldersFirst in:
    /Users/User/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-aqfmfwpjnumbrjdrdqwonfwvhzaz/Build/Intermediates/MyApp.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/aTarget.build/Objects-normal/i386/MyClass.o
    /Users/User/Documents/..[path]../MyFramework.framework/MyFramework(MyClass2.o)
ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Considerations:
- I'm not including any .m files (apparently a common error based on my research)
- Classes implemented in those files have different names in both files
- Note the library is in fact wrapped as a framework, but that's not the problem since I'm working with the library for a while without having this issue.

Thanks advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on a @Hermann's comment, I found the issue (which in fact wasn't complex :S)

My code was defining a method as follows in my .m file:

```
NSInteger comparePutFoldersFirst(id aValue1, id aValue2, void *context) {...}
```

This method apparently generates a global symbol that was the responsible of the conflict.

I was using that method for sorting an array, so I changed it for a block and the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a problem, if these are real properties or if they are real instance variables or properly declared class variables.

But sometimes, when you did not work too accurately, then it may have happend that these variables are really static or even global. 
That is when they are simply delared in the open space between mehods or between `@implementation` and method bodies.

Make sure that they are properly declared within `{ ... }` following an `@implementation` statement. I have read recently that you can have the brackets with iVars following an `@implementation` statement too but I never tried that. However, without those brackets they are just static or even global. That means that the same variable declared in two classes actually IS a duplicated symbol.

Quick&Dirty: Just rename one of them. 
Properly: Re-Structure your code a bit. It may be done with collectig them in the .h file follwoing the `@interface` and enclose them in brackets.

If you dont want them in the .h file, then begin your .m file with an empty category:

```
@interface myClass2 () {
   int localInstanceVar1;
   NSInteger *localInstanceOjbekct2;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick ansewer! I checked and there is no static/global variables. I'm on the restructure option now =D which its not the fastest option. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, that is what was wrong in one of my apps when I got this linker error. Did you try searching for `comparePutFoldersFirst` in your code?

Comment: ja! I thought "comparePutFoldersFirst" was part of the trace, but it was a c-like method defined in the .m that was conflicting!!!! Thanks!